# MySQL SELECT WHERE DATE is approx X days ago

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing a date column.

The table data is inserted via a cron job at irregular intervals, and not daily.

I'd like to select only the row that is closest to X days ago.

So for example if its June 30th and there is no entry for June 25th I'd like it to grab the entry from June 26th or 24th (whichever is newest and closest in time to 5 days ago), if there are no entries on the 26th or 24th then to look for 27th or 23rd, etc...

The date is stored as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You could use the between statement `WHERE date BETWEEN x ... y`

Comment: @Matthew On an answer I posted before I received feedback against using `BETWEEN` on `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` columns. I suggest you read this article: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @Barranka The only problem I see with `between` in that article is that the author doesn't understand how dates work.

Comment: @Matthew It is worth considering, given the experience of the author (somehow I think the author *does* know his stuff). Anyway, for critical tasks, it is always a good idea to double check results. If the `datetime` value includes hours, minutes and seconds, an expression like `t between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-05'` will *exclude* every value of t that is (strictly) greater than `2013-01-05 00:00:00` (for example: `2013-01-05 00:00:01`)... and that is most probably not what is desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the TIMESTAMP column is `insertion_ts` and `?` is bound to the DATE or TIMESTAMP you desire:

```
   SELECT *
    FROM tbl
ORDER BY 
         -- We want the closest insertion_ts to our target date ...
         ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ?, insertion_ts)) ASC,
         -- ... and will favor the more recent in the unlikely event of a tie
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ?, insertion_ts) DESC
   LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks pilcrow! Been trying to figure this out for a while, 1st post on stack overflow answered in 5 mins :)

Comment: @IanT, you're welcome.  Be sure to come back with more Q & A in the future! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
SELECT   id, date, ....
FROM     tbl
WHERE    date <= [your date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That won't do it:  the OP wants the "nearest" timestamp to the desired date, not the nearest timestamp prior to the desired date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(`date`, (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL X DAY)))) ASC
LIMIT 1
```